# Is the possibility to change a format address in Substrate?

Tags: rust, substrate

My question is based on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533691/can-we-use-a-different-address-format-in-substrate) and it seems to doesn't work.

I'm looking for any information on how I can change the address format from ss58 to bech32?

Do I need to implement?

> impl AddressMapping

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at https://github.com/interlay/interbtc as they are a btc polkadot bridge, so might have covered this ground.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem that

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9KfvhoqLJ4 - they change the address format in frontier to ethereum so it's possible. It will be in this video somewhere - it's a cracking talk (but may take some time to unpack).